# Android Php Server Connection

Tags: php, android, server, connection

I am trying to make an android app with php in a backend. In this login page I am trying to send login credentials to php file so I can echo that and store that value in variables. And also My php file is stored on server of www.myurl.com/myfolder/login.php. I know a lot more  about web development but this is my first experiment with android app. I even referred several online tutorials for this. All I see is using JSON and json_encode in php but that is not solving my problem. I think I am making some other mistake or is not able to locate an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to communicate data between php and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956561/simplest-way-to-communicate-data-between-php-and-android)

Comment: Yes my question is similar to that one but trying out those suggestion is not of any help. @LasVegasCoder

Comment: I would use a library as retrofit ( http://square.github.io/retrofit/ ) to make the php call and get the json response from that website as an object after it is parsed with gson. You can find examples about this on internet like https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792